# How can I display different dialogbox when I use Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There are two icon buttons on the UI, and the different confirm dialogbox will be displayed when I click different icon button.

The following code is ugly, I have to set different variable (`openDeleteDialog` and `openManualTranslateDialog`)  to control different dialogbox, but in fact,  the two variables have the same logic, they are only to control *Show* or *Hide* a dialogbox.

I don't know how to optimize these codes, could you give me some suggestions?

```
@Composable
fun ToolbarOfMore(   
    mInfo: MInfo,    
    toolbarOtherState: ToolbarOtherState = rememberToolbarOtherState(),
    recordSoundViewModel: RecordSoundViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    ShowOtherDialog(mInfo)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier          
    ) {   
        IconButton(          
            onClick = {             
               toolbarOtherState.set_openManualTranslateDialog(true)              
            }
        ) {
            IconBasedEnabledOrDisabled(icon = Icons.Outlined.SpatialAudio, dim = dim)
        }
   
        IconButton(
            enabled = true,
            onClick = {
                toolbarOtherState.set_openDeleteDialog(true)
            }
        ) {
            IconBasedEnabledOrDisabled(icon = Icons.Outlined.Delete, dim = dim)
        }      
    }
}


@Composable
fun ShowOtherDialog(
    mInfo: MInfo,
    toolbarOtherState: ToolbarOtherState = rememberToolbarOtherState(),
    recordSoundViewModel: RecordSoundViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
    val context = mContext

    ConfirmDialog(
        isShow = toolbarOtherState.openDeleteDialog,
        onDismiss = { toolbarOtherState.set_openDeleteDialog(false) },
        onConfirm = {
           ...
        },
        dialogContent = stringResource(R.string.dialog_delete_content)
    )

    ConfirmDialog(
        isShow = toolbarOtherState.openManualTranslateDialog,
        onDismiss = { toolbarOtherState.set_openManualTranslateDialog(false) },
        onConfirm = {
            ...
        },
        dialogContent = stringResource(R.string.dialog_manual_translate)
    )
}



class ToolbarOtherState   private constructor(context: Context) {

    var openDeleteDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    var openManualTranslateDialog by  mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    fun set_openDeleteDialog(isShow:Boolean) {
        openDeleteDialog = isShow
    }

    fun set_openManualTranslateDialog(isShow:Boolean) {
        openManualTranslateDialog = isShow
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: ToolbarOtherState ? = null
     
        fun getInstance(context: Context): ToolbarOtherState {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: ToolbarOtherState (context).also { instance=it }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun rememberToolbarOtherState(): ToolbarOtherState {
    val context = mContext
    return remember {
        ToolbarOtherState.getInstance(context)
    }
}


@Composable
fun ConfirmDialog(
    isShow: Boolean,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    yesTitle: String = stringResource(R.string.dialog_yes_title),
    noTitle:String = stringResource(R.string.dialog_no_title),
    dialogTitle:String =stringResource(R.string.dialog_warning_title),
    dialogContent:String ="Content"
) {
    if (isShow) {
        AlertDialog(

            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = onConfirm)
                { Text(text = yesTitle) }
            },

            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = onDismiss)
                { Text(text = noTitle) }
            },

            onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
            title = { Text(text =dialogTitle) },
            text = { Text(text = dialogContent) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have one state with an Enum. 1 for each dialog and an additional hidden state to hide a dialog.